# Ephesoft ghostscript error while building library and shared library

Tags: ghostscript, ephesoft

I am installing Ephesoft community edition 4.0.2.0 in Ubuntu 16, during the installation , I am getting error when it is trying to build library and shared library for ghostscript, and due to that the script 'install-helper' can not install tesseract, leptonica and imagemagic.
However , I tried to install it after changing the installation sequence and putting the Ghostscript at last in the sequence. Tesseract , leptonica and imagemagic has installed but getting error while builing library for ghostscript.

Thanks

Comment: You have not supplied anything which will help people to help you. You haven't quoted the error(s), nor described where you picked up the Ghostscript sources from, or which version of Ghostscript. Normally Ghostscript comes with a copy of all the 3rd party libraries it requires, as source, and builds those. Many OS packagers insist that the build should use system shared libraries instead. If you don't have those libraries, and don't have the Ghostscript copy of the sources for them, then the build will fail. Complain to the package manager.

Comment: Ephesoft community edition which I am using , is bydefault using ghostscript 9.10 version. The script 'install-helper' which is shell script comes with Ephesoft , installs all other software successfully like tesseract, imagemagic etc... but gives error on building library for ghostscript. I even tried to install it manually but it did not work.

Comment: You still haven't said in what way it 'doesn't work', if its a build error, then what's the error ? You could try getting the latest Ghostscript (9.21) building and installing that, and then configuring the other packages to use the installed version. Otherwise, well frankly it sounds like the 'Ephesoft' edition broke the code, so you may have to get them to help you (though of course the support is limited for open source users). Personally I'd get the latest Ghostscript and use that, 9.10 is 3 years old and has bugs and security vulnerabilities which are already fixed in the current version.

Comment: Thanks Kens, I would try to install the latest one (Ghostscript 9.21).